# why use the blank validator rule in the model for the ID field? cakephp

Tags: validation, cakephp, model

I'm new to cake and I just want to understand the logic behind this. I know that the blank rule is used to make sure that the field is left blank or that white space characters are present in it's value but don't we always want our ID to be equal to some numeric value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user is submitting data that's used to create a new entry in the database, you don't want to let them choose the id. When the id field is blank the database (or the model) will generate the new id automatically.

Usually the rule is used together with `'on' => 'create'`:

```
'id' => array(
    'rule' => 'blank',
    'on' => 'create'
)
```

...which basically means "when creating, don't accept id from the user." Without this rule the user could choose the database id or pass an existing one and overwrite data.

Answer (score 0):

You must have seen that from here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::blank.

There are many situations that this might be handy.

1. Lets just say that in your view you have a form for adding a new record. Even if you don't have a field of id in your form an evil user can submit along with the rest of the data an id. If you submit an ID with your data then when you execute the following in your controller

`$this->MyController->save($this->request->data)`

Cake will update an existing record if a record with the id exists.

2. You might have an auto increment in your database so you don't want an id to be submitted because the database handles the id numbering.

Maybe there are more cases that do not come in mind.

Comment: That's exactly where I must have saw it. Thanks your answer helped